# Async is driving me mad

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux, use-effect

I would like my program to run the use effect before it attempts to render anything. The plan is to fetch the data with the `getTable()` function and then store the data in redux, and then break up the current js file up some more and be able to access the data in all my classes.

So here is the problem it is calling the createMap function 4 or 5 times and most importantly it is doing it before the program has a chance to add the data to the redux store and have proper data for the createMap function to run.

```
import react, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import dom from 'react-dom'
import L from "leaflet";
//import MarkerCluster from "./Markers"
import '../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import '../../node_modules/react-leaflet-markercluster/dist/styles.min.css'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
import MarkerClusterGroup from 'react-leaflet-markercluster';
import './CSS/Pmap.css'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

function Pmap() {
    const state = useSelector((state) => state)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    console.log(state)
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('use effect')
        getTable();

    }, [])

    const storeData = (data) => {
        console.log(`store data called ${data.rows}`)
        dispatch({
            type: "addData",
            payload: { rows: data.rows, rowCount: data.rowCount }
        })
        console.log(`store data finished` + state)
    }

    const getTable =  () => {
        try {
            const response = axios.post("/api/get/1919")
            storeData(response.data);
            setLoading(false);
            setData(response.data)
            setRows(response.data.rows)



        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }


    }

    //********************************************* Map ************************************ */
    const customMarker = new L.Icon({
        iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
        iconSize: [25, 41],
        iconAnchor: [10, 41],
        popupAnchor: [2, -40]
    });


    function createMap() {
        console.log("map function called for");

        return (
            <div>
                <MapContainer center={[43.458, -80.503]} zoom={12} scrollWheelZoom={true} className='markercluster-map'>
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&copy; <a href="&copy; <a href="https://stadiamaps.com/">Stadia Maps</a>, &copy; <a href="https://openmaptiles.org/">OpenMapTiles</a> &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributorshttp://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url="https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
                    />
                    <MarkerClusterGroup>
                        {console.log(`state.rows : ${state}`)}
                        {
                            state.rows.map((element) => {
                                return (
                                    <Marker
                                        position={[element.Lat, element.Long]}
                                        icon={customMarker}
                                        key={element.OID} />
                                )

                            })
                        }

                    </MarkerClusterGroup>
                </MapContainer>
            </div>
        )



    }
    /**********************************************End of Map ******************************* */
    // ********************************************TABLE************************************
    const columns = [
        { id: 'last_name', label: 'Last Name', minWidth: 170 },
        { id: 'first_name', label: 'First Name', minWidth: 100 },
        { id: 'edited_occ', label: 'Occupation', minWidth: 170 },
        { id: 'Chgd_add', label: 'Address', minWidth: 170 }
    ];


    const useStyles = makeStyles({
        root: {
            width: '100%',
        },
        container: {
            maxHeight: 440,
        },
    });

    function StickyHeadTable() {
        console.log("Sticky Head Table Called")
        const classes = useStyles();
        const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
        const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(10);

        const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
            setPage(newPage);
        };

        const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
            setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
            setPage(0);
        };

        return (
            <Paper className={classes.root}>
                <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
                    <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                                {columns.map((column) => (
                                    <TableCell
                                        key={column.id}
                                        align={column.align}
                                        style={{ minWidth: column.minWidth }}
                                    >
                                        {column.label}
                                    </TableCell>
                                ))}
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            {rows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map((row) => {
                                return (
                                    <TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={row.code}>
                                        {columns.map((column) => {
                                            const value = row[column.id];
                                            return (
                                                <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align}>
                                                    {column.format && typeof value === 'number' ? column.format(value) : value}
                                                </TableCell>
                                            );
                                        })}
                                    </TableRow>
                                );
                            })}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </TableContainer>
                <TablePagination
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 100]}
                    component="div"
                    count={rows.length}
                    rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                    page={page}
                    onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                    onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                />
            </Paper>
        );
    }


    // ******************************************* End of table *********************************




    return (
        <div className="Pmap">


            <div>
                {createMap()}
            </div>
            <div>
                {StickyHeadTable()}
            </div>
            {console.log(`state.rows end :  ${JSON.stringify(state)}`)}

        </div>
    )
} export default Pmap;
```

Here is the console log, all this is running before the useEffect which i thought should run first before anything else has a chance to run. I also checked it is eventually adding the data to redux just not before it is needed.

[image]

Comment: `useEffect` runs after every completed render, not before.

Comment: `axios.post("/api/get/1919")` returns a Promise, which doesn't have a `data` property, hence the `state.rows` likely being undefined in a subsequent render cycle (IDK, maybe your state/reducer/selector also isn't correct). Did you mean to make `getTable` `async` and `await` the response? Or maybe you meant to use the Promise chain?

Answer (score -1):

The earliest moment `useEffects` runs is after the first render.
And even if it were running before: fetching is an asynchronous action, so at some point your application will render and data fetching might be finished much later than that.

You will need to render a "loading" indicator and then render the actual contents after loading is finished. Also, you really do not want to skip or delay rendering something like that. On a bad connection, that loading could take seconds to minutes. You don't want people to think your app crashed because it hasn't renderd anything yet.

So `{createMap()}` becomes `{loading ? "please wait, loading" : createMap()}`